# Can I define a method inside a method?

Tags: java

I have a question

if I do method in method ,is it right or no?

like

```
public static void Hanoof(){

    public static int Hano(){

    } 
}
```

or

```
public static double Hanoof(){
    public static double Hano(){

    } 
}
```

or is it impossible ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this in Java is through local classes, i.e. classes that are defined in the scope of a method:

```
public double Hanoof(){

    class HanoMaker{ 

        public double Hano(){
          // do stuff here
        } 

    }
    double hano = new HanoMaker().hano();
    return hano;
}
```

This is however seldom used and I'm not sure if such classes may have static methods.

Comment: Can you make the nested method static?

Comment: @PeterLawrey the outer method? Good question, probably not, as that would make the inner class static, too.

Comment: I guess its a typo `public double Hanoof` with missing method `()` ?

Comment: @sansix actually copy / paste from the OP

Comment: Local classes cannot be declared static, and therefore cannot have static members.

Comment: @MikeStrobel see, thought so

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd LoL I thought its your typo - whereas I also overlooked that part in OPs Ques.

Comment: @sansix I didn't see it either :-)

Answer (score 5):

**No** you can't, Java doesn't allow nested methods. 
you might have seen nested functions in JavaScript but then again `Java != JavaScript`

**EDIT:**

as `Sean Patrick Floyd` suggests: you can achieve this using [Local Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) and also check 
notes on [when to use such classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html)